# Sending a character 'A' through blinking led

Tags: arduino-uno, led, signal-processing

> How do i code to send a character 'A' to the arduino through a blinking led? 
>    i am doing a project about data transmission. i really need help&some guide.
>    Material used are arduino uno r3,white led and a resistor.

MY OUPUT IN SERIAL MONITOR

Insert letter:

01000001 65  - Character A

00001010 10  - when i send/enter

CODE

```
 int LEDTrans = 13;
int timeWaitOn = 1000; //milisec (1 sec)
int timeWaitOff = 1000; // milisec (1 sec)
byte byteRead;

void setup() {                
// Turn the Serial Protocol ON
  Serial.begin(9600);


 Serial.print("Insert letter:");
 Serial.println(" ");
}

void loop() {

digitalWrite(LEDTrans,HIGH); //turn the led on
delay(timeWaitOn); //delay in millisec (1 sec)
digitalWrite(LEDTrans,LOW); //turn the led off
delay(timeWaitOff); //wait a sec


   /*  check if data has been sent from the computer: */
  if (Serial.available()) {


     byteRead = Serial.read();
    // will print the binary representation of 'byteRead' as 8 characters of '1's and '0's, MSB first.
for ( uint8_t bitMask = 128; bitMask != 0; bitMask = bitMask >> 1 ) {

      if ( byteRead & bitMask ) {

    Serial.write('1');
  } else {
    Serial.write('0');
  }  
}

Serial.write("    ");
Serial.println(byteRead);    //send back the actual ASCII code
}


}
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: There is no code intended to send something over a LED. Try googling something like Arduino light data transmission and similar terms. There are libraries for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transmit a sequence of bit using arduino uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52352/transmit-a-sequence-of-bit-using-arduino-uno)

Comment: Huh, I'm confused. You asked this exact  question here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52352/transmit-a-sequence-of-bit-using-arduino-uno/52363#52363 and the given answer is also the exact functional equivalent, except that the data is coming from the serial monitor..

Comment: i'm learning a lot from this website. im a beginner and i want to learn a lot of things. your explanation and help was really helpful :) im really grateful for that. thank you so much.

Comment: I want you to state, very clearly, what you want the code to do. For example: When I send "A" I expect a pause of 1 second with the LED off, then the LED to be on for 1 second, then the LED to be off for 5 seconds, then on for one second, and then off for one second (giving a total of 8 seconds to send the letter "A"). If that is not what you want please state what you **do** want.

Comment: Now get it. I saw the LED on and off as you describe above. Therefore it takes only 8 seconds to send letter 'A'. Thank youu veryyy much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing '0' or '1' set the LED pin off or on, like this:

```
const int LEDTrans = 13;
const int timeWaitOn = 1000;  // millisec (1 sec)
const int timeWaitOff = 1000; // millisec (1 sec)

void setup() {
  // Turn the Serial Protocol ON
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Send letter:");
  pinMode (LEDTrans, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  /*  check if data has been sent from the computer: */
  if (Serial.available()) {
    byte byteRead = Serial.read();
    // will print the binary representation of 'byteRead' as 8 characters of '1's and '0's, MSB first.
    for ( uint8_t bitMask = 128; bitMask != 0; bitMask >>= 1 ) {
      if ( byteRead & bitMask ) {
        digitalWrite(LEDTrans, HIGH); //turn the led on
        delay(timeWaitOn); //delay in millisec (1 sec)
        digitalWrite(LEDTrans, LOW); //turn the led off
      } else {
        delay(timeWaitOff); //wait a sec
      } // end of if
    } // end of for loop
  } // end of if something available
} // end of loop
```

---

> how do i count the flashes? is it based on the binary 01000001?

Here's the problem ... according to what your question seems to ask for, you are wanting an LED to flash for a 1 and be off for a zero. So the results (which my code provides) would look like this:

[image: Example 1]

So, you get two flashes, the first one second after it starts, then there is a gap of 5 seconds, and then another flash. That would be 01000001.

However, how do you know when to start counting flashes? It might be:

[image: Example 2]

That would be 00000001.

Or even:

[image: Example 3]

That would be 10000010.

You can see, can't you, that you can't make any meaningful deduction at the receiving end about what the character is?

---

So what asynchronous serial (normal serial on an Arduino) does is have a **Start Bit** which signals when to start counting, like this:

[image: Serial with start bit]

Normally the serial port is high (continuous 1s) and then when a 0 arrives that means "start counting". So, you wait 1½ bits of time and then sample at the known baud rate. In your example, where you want 1 second per bit, the baud rate would be 1 (one bit per second). Thus, you sample every one second. Normally baud rates are somewhat faster than that, like 9600 or 115200 samples per second.

Also there is a **Stop Bit** which is always a 1. This guarantees that there will be at least a single 1 at the end of each byte, so that we can tell when the next start bit arrives.

---

There are *other ways of doing this*, for example a short pulse might represent a zero, and a longer pulse represent a one. In that case, any pulse at all could represent the start of a byte, and then you just measure how many short pulses, and how many long pulses, you get (for some definition of "short" and "long").

Comment: thank you soo much the blinking happened. but i am a bit confused. I count the on and off for the led to see the character of 'A' in binary that is 01000001. but it didn't happened.

Comment: Really? I changed the baud rate to 115200, I hope you noticed. If I send "A" then I get the LED flashing after 1 second and after 7 seconds, which is right: `01000001`. You expect two flashes, one a second in, and one seven seconds in. The rest of the time the LED is off (that is a zero).

Comment: Oh. I noticed that,but i tried to change to 9600.Maybe that's why. Do i really must use the baud rate 115200 to achieve 01000001 ?What type of library should I import in this coding?Where can i get the library?This arduino acts as a transmitter to send the character 'A' and the receiver is an application. Do you have any suggestion how can i synchronize both of them?Can i have your email. i have a lot to ask.

Comment: The baud rate is only for you to send a character to the sketch from the serial monitor. The rate at which the LED blinks is set in your code, currently one bit per second. There is no library you need. Why do you think you want one? If you have more questions please post them here.

Comment: I thought I need one. I went through other projects they import libraries. But I currently don't understand what you mean by >>    flashing after 1 second and after 7 seconds, which is right: 01000001. You expect two flashes, one a second in, and one seven seconds in. The rest of the time the LED is off (that is a zero).

Comment: I'm curious to know what **you** are expecting to happen. Please state how often you expect the LED to blink and at what intervals. Surely 01000001 represents two blinks? (There are two "1"s there). What else could it represent?

Comment: I am sorry that I made you confused. How do i count the flashing of the led that you mention before?for 1 how many flash&seconds that it represents?and for 0 how many seconds does the led went off? i want to transmit the 'A' in binary for 10 seconds. If the led is on,does it represent 1?i am a bit confused there.When the led is off it represents 0?

Comment: how do i count the flashes? is it based on the binary 01000001?how do i count the flashes? is it based on the binary 01000001?the pins that i connect the jumper to the led should be pin 13 and tx is it right?i want to transmit 'A'.

Comment: Nick, I tried to count the blinking of the LED on the arduino board. it shows flashing after 1 seconds and after 7 seconds. but when i attached a white LED using the jumpers,the flahsing is different. i count the flashing, when the LED starts to went off as 0, then it when on as 1. the white led blinks 0 1 0 1 0(5 to 6 sec) 1 0 1.  Or i should count on the second blinking that shows 010000010 ?

Comment: *the pins that i connect the jumper to the led should be pin 13 and tx is it right* - No, pin 13 and Ground, with a current-limiting resistor between the LED and ground, for example 330 ohms.

Comment: *how do i count the flashes?* - what do you mean by that? When you see a flash you count it? You also make a note of the time between the flashes. I am completely unclear, after reading these questions, about what you are expecting the code to do, and if you can't state that then neither I, nor anyone else (including you) can make it do that thing, whatever it is.

Comment: Now i understand. I am expecting the arduino to be a transmitter that transmits character 'A' through pin 13 on the arduino.  You helped me a lot Nick. Thank you very very much.